# Using Datastore composite filters in an Objectify query

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am in the process of defining a query in which one of the filters can have multiple values (which naturally translates into an `OR`). However, as I have come to realize, query filters in Objectify are aggregated into an `AND` operation, and even the 'in' operator is not supported by the underlying Google Cloud SDK in the version 6.

I am trying to use Datastore composite filters to fulfill my need, as this could be a possibility to aggregate predicates with an OR operator, and then pass the constructed Filter object to the Objectify `Query.filter()` method.

Now here's the issue: the Filter object constructed with composite filters is different from the object accepted by the Objectify `.filter()` method, the latter being a nested class of `StructuredQuery`.

Is it possible to use composite filters in an Objectify query? If so, I would appreciate an example of how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the new Cloud Datastore Java client library (used by Objectify6) with the old Google App Engine SDK (used by Objectify5).

The old GAE SDK supports `OR` filters. The new one does not (yet). You may wish to request this feature from Google here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java

As an aside: I believe the old SDK was actually processing `OR` filters by running two separate queries and merging the results client-side. You can do something similar yourself if you're in a hurry and don't want to go back to the old GAE SDK (which only works in GAE Standard).

Comment: Actually I'm not confusing the two, that's exactly my question, even though I probably did not make myself clear enough. I'm wondering since this capability is not offered anymore in the new underlying cloud datastore library, is there an effective way to achieve an OR operation with Objectify nevertheless?